# WPF - Selected item in a child data grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a grid inside a grid. When I select an item from the parent grid it works as expected. When I selecte an item from the child grid, firstly it binds to the selected item, but then when I try to do an action (remove it for example), the selected item becomes null. Here is my code:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView name="parent"
      <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
         <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <telerik:RadGridView Name="child" ...                                 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=SelectedChild, Mode=TwoWay}">

   public Child SelectedChild
   {
            get
            {
                return selectedChild;
            }
            set
            {
                if (selectedChild!= value)
                {
                    selectedChild= value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedChild));
                }
            }
    }

internal void RemoveChild()
{
    Child toberemoved = SelectedChild     (this is where it returns null)  
    ...
}
```

Comment: When is SelectedChild set to null?

Comment: @mm8 In the viewmodel I have a method that should remove the selected Child from the list. But SelectedChild returns null (see above code)

Comment: So SelectedChild never gets set to a value?

Comment: @mm8 It does work fine in the get set

Comment: See my first comment again then. When does the property gets set back to null?

Comment: @mm8 when I try to use SelectedChild in the RemoveChild method

Comment: No. Then you are only accessing the *getter* of the property. This doesn't *set* the property. Please provide a repo of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve